# Ad Comments to ads in mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, firebase, admob

I would like my app users to be able to add comments to any ad displayed on the screen and view comments written by other users,

the comments will be saved in firebase and retrieved when the ad is displayed

my ads are displayed in the middle of a list ( native ads ) in both android (java) and ios (swift)

is there a way to do that with admob or any other ad service ?

thank you

Comment: If you hover over the downvote button, it says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)". Perfect match for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Admob does not provide a commenting system for ads, and I don't know of any ad provider that does.

You would have to implement this yourself. I imagine there is some way to get the id of the creative that is displayed in the ad, then you could store the comments in your own firebase database.

I'm not sure why you would want to take comments on ads as this may reflect negatively on the advertiser, or someone may comment "Click on this" which is against Admob policy. If you have comments elsewhere on other items in your list then I would probably disable commenting on ad items.